# Want to load users already selected interests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multi-select

Using react multi select to choose a users interests that is saved in mongoDB. The issue is that I want the users already selected choices to be reflected within the multi-select even if i refresh. As currently if you refresh the page it clears the selections and if you submit changes with a blank interest spot, it creates an empty interest array.

user model

```
const model = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: [roles.ADMIN, roles.STUDENT, roles.ALUMNI],
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    major: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    minor: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    interests: {
      type: Array ,
      required: false,
      default : []
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default : "/images/default.png"
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = new mongoose.model("User", model);
```

How its stored in mongo

[image]

Code for multi-select and things involved with it

```
<Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
  <Form.Label>Interests</Form.Label>
  <Select
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={colourOptions}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
    styles={customStyles}
    value={colourOptions.filter(obj => selectedValue.includes(obj.value))} // set selected values
    onChange={handleChange}                    
  />
</Form.Group>
```

```
 const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(x => x.value) : []);
  }

  const customStyles = {
      option: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        color: state.isSelected ? 'red' : 'black',
        padding: 5,
      })
  }
  const colourOptions = [
    { value: "Artificial Intelligence", label: "Artificial Intelligence" },
    { value: "Product Management", label: "Product Management" },
    { value: "Mental Health", label: "Mental Health" },
    { value: "Physics", label: "Physics" },
    { value: "Statistics", label: "Statistics" },
    { value: "Technology", label: "Technology" },
    { value: "Finance", label: "Finance" },

];
```

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = e.currentTarget;

    e.stopPropagation();
    setValidated(true);

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      return;
    }

    const user = {
      name: nameRef.current.value,
      email: emailRef.current.value,
      role: roleRef.current.value,
      major: majorRef.current.value,
      minor: minorRef.current.value,
      interests: selectedValue,
      profilePic: profilePicRef.current.value,
    };

    onSubmit(user);
  };
```

visual representation of multi-select
[image]

Everything is working except loading the users already selected interests into the drop down multi select so that it doesn't clear a users interest if they don't re-choose their interests while changing something else and submitting it. Tried to do something with default values but the code `value={colourOptions.filter(obj => selectedValue.includes(obj.value))} // set selected values` is kind of messing with doing it that way.